# Spring Java API returning byte[] variable with ""

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Good day!
My Api returns byte variable like this "..." but retrofit in my android application can read only like this [...] how can i change response.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class bookEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long books_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] cover;
```

Service:

```
public Iterable<bookEntity> findAll()
    {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getAllBook()
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.findAll());
    }
```